# How to check if a certain .txt file exists in java

Tags: java, io

A program that I am making will access words.txt file.
How do I programmatically check if that file exists using `java.io`?

Comment: maybe File.exists ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [File.exists()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists--)

```
File f = new File("filepath");
System.out.println(f.exists());
```